# How to comprehend complex maps defined by iteration?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

Define the map
$$f(z) = e^{iz}/z$$
which we will iterate as $f(f(z))$, $f(f(f(z)))$, $\cdots$, meaning, $e^{ie^{iz}/z}/z$, $e^{ie^{ie^{iz}/z}/z}/z$, and so on. Now, what can we say about the limit of this sequence of compositions? Can we even dis/prove the existence of the limit as a map $\mathbb R\to \mathbb C$ or even $\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$? And further how can we classify the map - in terms of its poles and asymptotes, or something else? If the limit exists, what kind of structure can we see into it? I've plotted the partial summations and it doesn't look to me like this will converge.

I suppose another question might be what are the constraints on initial $f$ so that it does converge?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

$$f(z)=\frac{e^{iz}}{z}$$

For $n\to\infty$ (where $n$ is the number of iterations)
$$g(x)=f(f(f(...f(x)...)))\text{ but also }g(x)=f(\underbrace{f(f(...f(f(x))...))}_{g(x)})$$
So
$$g(z)=f(g(z))$$
$$g(z)=\frac{e^{ig(z)}}{g(z)}$$
$$g(z)^2=e^{ig(z)}$$
Let $W(z)$ the Lambert function, the inverse function of $ze^{z}$
$$g(z)^2=e^{ig(z)}$$
$$g(z)=e^{\frac{i}{2}g(z)}$$
$$g(z)e^{-\frac{i}{2}g(z)}=1$$
$$-\frac{i}{2}g(z)e^{-\frac{i}{2}g(z)}=-\frac{i}{2}$$
$$-\frac{i}{2}g(z)=W\left(-\frac{i}{2}\right)$$
$$g(z)=-\frac{2}{i}W\left(-\frac{i}{2}\right)$$
$$g(z)=2i\cdot W\left(-\frac{i}{2}\right)\approx -0.7852571+
0.32519929i$$

Comment: So if $f^{\circ n}(z)$ has a limit $n\to\infty$, it must be the constant function with image $[2iW(-i/2)]$ - that's great. But did that prove that $f^{\circ n}(z)$ actually converges for $n \to \infty$? I guess you just need to show that for any finite $z\in \mathbb C$, you have an increasing sequence $N \subset \mathbb N$ with an associated decreasing sequence $|f^{\circ n}(z)-2iW(-i/2)|$ where $|\cdot|$ is absolute value.

Comment: In fact there are countable many $W$ and I assume you chose only the principal branch. Also I found my real part of the principal W to be positive. For example $11.74720116795 -5.099901361204047054585i$, corresponding to the $W_{-1}$ choice also satisfies $z = e^{iz}/z$. So you have proved that if the limit $f$ exists, then it must be one of a countable choice of maps, but you haven't shown which one yet.

Comment: Let me know if you have some thoughts regarding my response - Thank you.

Comment: See [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/20352/2023/9/10)

Comment: @MathAttack - what is this in reference to?

Comment: You edited your answer but it is still wrong.. Check your answer as the sign of your real part is off. Also you still did not answer the question as you did not address convergence - see my comments above.